# Jquery slide-out bottom-top mouseover menu problem on loading a new page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, menu, hover

i'm struggling with converting a menu from mootools to jquery. there are various reasons why i have to switch the js framework and i need some help here because i quite new to jquery.

first the working mootools version on the live site: http://www.kieleconomcis.de

as you can see the menu moves up on hover, reveals the sub menu and **stays up** when you click a link and load the page.

now that i have to convert this into jquery i also want to be able to **control the heigth** of each menu individually, so it a) looks more like a bar graph and b) i can place 4 submenus :)

i played around, copy&pasted, tried&errored and ended up with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobiasmay/jEJTR) here.

my **problem** is - i guess - that i have a `$('div.nav_body').hide();` but i need to tell it that it has to ignore the effect if the element before it has an `id="visible"`

here is some of the code so you can see what i need to trigger:

```
    <h4 id="visible">Über uns</h4>
        <div id="nav2-body" class="nav_body">
```

thanks for any adice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `:not()` and `:has()` selector works:

```
$('div.nav_container:not(:has(#visible)) .nav_body').hide();
```

The `filter()` method works as well:

```
$('div.nav_body').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).prev().is("#visible");
}).hide();
```

Or use `.not()` to remove the one submenu from the to-be-hidden items:

```
$('div.nav_body').not($("#visible").next()).hide();
```

I tested all three in your fiddle. I can't really say which one I like best, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's parent h4 has it's id set to visible

```
if ($('div.nav_body').parent('h4').attr('id') == 'visible')
```